# Spawning sprites randomly on x-axis

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite

Hi I need to spawn balloons which are my sprites along the bottom of the x axis out of the screen randomly. I used this code from Ray Wenderliches website but when i click the button that starts the spawning they don't spawn?

```
 @implementation MyScene2



 - (void)addMonster {

// Create sprite
SKSpriteNode * monster = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"balloon11.png"];

// Determine where to spawn the monster along the X axis
int minX = monster.size.height / 2;
int maxX = self.frame.size.height - monster.size.height / 2;
int rangeX = maxX - minX;
int actualX = (arc4random() % rangeX) + minX;

// Create the monster slightly off-screen along the right edge,
// and along a random position along the X axis as calculated above
monster.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width + monster.size.width/2, actualX);
[self addChild:monster];

// Determine speed of the monster
int minDuration = 2.0;
int maxDuration = 4.0;
int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
int actualDuration = (arc4random() % rangeDuration) + minDuration;

   // Create the actions
SKAction * actionMove = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(-monster.size.width/2, actualX)   
 duration:actualDuration];
SKAction * actionMoveDone = [SKAction removeFromParent];
[monster runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[actionMove, actionMoveDone]]];

}


  - (void)updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate:(CFTimeInterval)timeSinceLast {

  self.lastSpawnTimeInterval += timeSinceLast;
  if (self.lastSpawnTimeInterval > 1) {
    self.lastSpawnTimeInterval = 0;
     [self addMonster];
   }
 }



  - (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {
 // Handle time delta.
 // If we drop below 60fps, we still want everything to move the same distance.
 CFTimeInterval timeSinceLast = currentTime - self.lastUpdateTimeInterval;
 self.lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime;
 if (timeSinceLast > 1) { // more than a second since last update
    timeSinceLast = 1.0 / 60.0;
    self.lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime;
    }

  [self updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate:timeSinceLast];

 }
```

Comment: Use essentially the same method of randomizing an x value, making static your y values.

Comment: Are you using SpriteKit?  Please show us the code you are using to spawn these sprites.

Comment: @WolfLink they don't spawn at the bottom of the screen and I added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem lies in this lines of code:

```
monster.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width + monster.size.width/2 , actualX);
```

That method works like this: `CGPointMake( x_coord , y_coord );`.

Right now, you are setting the x value to width of the frame plus the width of the sprite, so this will cause the sprite to be spawned off the screen.  You are giving the y coordinate the randomized value.  Instead, use

```
CGPointMake(actualX , self.frame.size.height);
```

Now there is another problem with this code.  These coordinates are based on the view, but `monster.position` is based on the `SKScene`.  The `SKScene` origin usually does not match up with the origin for the view.  So you have to do it like this:

```
monster.position = [CGPointMake(actualX , self.frame.size.height); locationInNode: self];
```

Also, I noticed that you are using `frame.size.width` for intended Y axis coordinates and `frame.size.height` for intended X axis coordinates.  Width is for x and height is for y, so make sure you are using those properly.